# Loading data into Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, etl

my question is the following:

Let's say I have a json file that I want to load into big query.
It contains these two lines of data.

```
{"value":"123"}
{"value": 123 }
```

I have defined the following schema for my data.

```
[
  { "name":"value", "type":"String"}
]
```

When I try to load the json file into big query it will fail with the following error:
 Field:value: Could not convert value to string

Is there a way to get around this issue other than transforming the data in the json file?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems pretty impossible to me considering the load must have a valid matching schema. However, you can update the schema of the table after it has been loaded to BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you Shayan. That's what I thought as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *maxBadRecords* property on the load job to skip a number of errors but still load the data.

Following your example, you could still load the data if you set it as:

```
"configuration": {
    "load": {
      "maxBadRecords": 1,
     }
}
```

This is a way to get around the issue while still loading your JSON data into the table, just that the erroneous rows will be skipped.  If loading a list of files, you could set it to be a function of the number of files that you are loading (e.g. maxBadRecords = 20 * fileCount)